# How do I display date and time for multiple time zones?

Tags: datetime

I am webmaster at http://www.archerpoint.com. We would like to display our events in both Eastern and Pacific time. I only know how to control the system time zone or let the user set their own time zone, but I do not know how to display a single time entry as two separate time zones without hacking code or creating and displaying two separate entries, one for each time zone. Is there a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to save date-time values in UTC format and while displaying them you can use [format_date](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_date/7) function

where you will need to pass timezone value to its parameter.